# How to add dictionary inside of an array to UItableview using insertRowsAtIndexPaths?

Tags: iphone, arrays, uitableview, dictionary, cell

How do I add the result of **getnewdata** to my existing tableView using **insertRowsAtIndexPaths**? I found several examples but cannot figure out.

```
- (void)getfirstdata {
     [...] //get JSON data
     self.data = jsonResult; //a dictionary inside of an array
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)getnewdata {
     [...] //get new JSON data which has to be added to top of the table
     self.data = jsonnewResult; //a dictionary inside of an array
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}

(UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) table_view cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) index_path
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    id celldata = [self.data objectAtIndex:[index_path row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [celldata valueForKeyPath:@"user.name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [celldata objectForKey:@"text"];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: You must be a ruby developer :-).  Objective-c convention is camelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For get new, you want to add to your data, so...

```
- (void)getnewdata {
     [...] //get new JSON data which has to be added to top of the table
     [self.data addObjectsFromArray:jsonResult];
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Make sure self.data is an NSMutableArray.

**Edit**

It just occurred to me that you might want the new data on top....

```
NSMutableArray *newModel = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:jsonResult];
[newModel addObjectsFromArray:self.data];
self.data = newModel;
```

Comment: thanks this works fine, unfortunately without **insertRowsAtIndexLevel**